# Natural Language Processing (NLP) open source algorithms

Tags: algorithms

I am looking for a way to give an algorithm (service) a sentence, and it will tell me if its positive context or negative or even neutral.

Does such a service exist?

Comment: Algorithm cannot be open-source. Algorithm is an idea. Code implementing an algorithm can be open-source.

Comment: ai.stackexchange.com just went into public beta today or yesterday, so you can check there too :)

Answer (score 6):

**The [OpenNLP site](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/projects.html) may help you**

The link refers to a long list of projects that are using OpenNLP to solve natural language processing problems.

Also, since you seem to be looking for a Sentiment and Opinion Mining application, perhaps the open source [RapidMiner application](http://rapid-i.com/content/view/26/201/) may be of interest.

Here is a [quote describing it](http://www.b-eye-network.com/view/9516):

> The software supports a wide variety
>   of clustering, classification and
>   other data mining functions.
>   Text-related modules include the Word
>   Vector Tool (WVT), Named Entity
>   Recognition (NER) and Data Stream
>   plug-ins. According to Rapid-I
>   cofounder and managing director Ralf
>   Klinkenberg, RapidMiner responds to a
>   very wide set of text-processing needs
>   including news filtering, email
>   routing, **sentiment analysis and
>   opinion mining**, and general
>   information extraction. According to
>   Klinkenberg, RapidMiner allows users
>   to combine unstructured data (text
>   documents) and structured data
>   (database tables, time series data,
>   audio data, etc.).